# Live Line chart in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5

I want to draw a line chart in iOS. for which I have coded following. I am using [PCLineChartView](https://github.com/honcheng/iOSPlot/tree/master/iOSPlot/Shared).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Creating a LineChart View

    PCLineChartView *lineChartView = [[PCLineChartView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, [self.view bounds].size.width-20, [self.view bounds].size.height-20)];
    [lineChartView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    lineChartView.minValue = 0;
    lineChartView.maxValue = 100;
    [self.view addSubview:lineChartView];

    //Associating Data with Line Chart

    NSMutableArray *components = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [self getGraphData];
    NSMutableArray *data = [result valueForKey:@"data"];

    for (NSDictionary *graphInfo in data) {
        PCLineChartViewComponent *component = [[PCLineChartViewComponent alloc]init];
        [component setTitle:@"title"];
        [component setPoints:graphInfo [@"data"]];
        [component setShouldLabelValues:NO];
        [component setColour:PCColorRed];
        [components addObject:component];
    }

    [lineChartView setComponents:components];
    [lineChartView setXLabels:[result valueForKey:@"xLabels"]];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

In the above code I have taken already generated data set. But the problem is that data is a live stream. I want to show a live stream data on the line chart. Please suggest me that how to proceed. I am a newbie. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an NSTimer like :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
```

And then according to your interval rate , timer will trigger "targetMethod:"

You can then update your line chart in your "targetMethod:"

Hope this helps!